# Oracle SQL : Pattern matching using LIKE operator to discover two word patterns

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, sql-like

I am trying to figure out how to query a column for a two word pattern like "allergic response" or "allergy response". I tried the below

- `LIKE '% allerg% response %'` but this matches strings like "Allergic
  reaction on 1/1/2010.... no response yet...."
- Tried word boundary `LIKE '% \ballerg%\b response %'`. This
  expression seems to be wrong. never worked

Basically I am looking to match consecutive words in which one of the words can take many values. I really dont want to list out all possible values in a `LIKE '..' OR LIKE '..'` .

Can someone give me some tip on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the regular expression `\S*` (zero-or-more non-white-space characters) or `\w*` (zero-or-more word characters) to match any ending to a word:

```
WITH phrases ( phrase ) AS (
  SELECT 'Allergic Response' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Allergy response' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Allergy gives a response to ...' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT phrase
FROM   phrases
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( phrase, 'Allerg\S* response', 'i' );
```

**Outputs**:

```
PHRASE               
----------------------
Allergic Response      
Allergy response
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks MT0!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the or operator `|` and group the alternatives inside parenthesis

For your example, you'll need the following regex:

```
allerg(ic|y) response
```

So your query becomes something like:

```
... WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (col_name, 'allerg(ic|y) response', 'i');
```

Remove the `'i'` parameter for case sensitive matching

And as a side note, oracle curiously has no word boundary regex operator !!  => [source](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm)

Comment: Thanks Enissay! This solution works for my problem. But I think the approach mentioned below by MT0 is more generic.